# Modernizr property required not defined

Tags: modernizr

I have this annoying problem which I don't seem to solve.

```
console.log(Modernizr);
```

this works just fine, but when I type

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.required) {
    alert("whatever");
} else {
    alert("whatever again");
}
```

then javascript error says "Cannot read property "required" of undefined".

Anyone know a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means that `Modernizr` is defined, but not `Modernizr.inputtypes`. Are you certain that the test is included in your build?

That being said, `required` [is not one of the tests that inputtypes provides](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/inputtypes.js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I meant Modernizr.input.required. However, none of them are working really. Modernizr.inputtypes.email, Modernizr.audio.mp3, ... none of them work

Comment: then that probably means inputtypes is not in your build. look at the source, and check to see if inputtypes is there

Comment: They are, 'inputtypes' and 'input' are in the source

Comment: if you are certain they are in the file, and not showing up on the modenrizr object, you should open up a bug report on the github repo for Modernizr